# How does spelling check extensions like 'Grammarly' and 'LanguageTool' work on a Google Docs page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-docs, languagetool, grammarly

As a Chrome extension developer, I am developing an extension like 'Grammarly' and 'LanguageTool'. In a typical webpage rendered through DOM nodes, I can achieve the desired effect by utilizing the `getClients()` API along with a positioning and overlay strategy. However, this approach proves ineffective on Google Docs pages, given that Google Docs is currently rendered using canvas.([discussion about this](https://github.com/Amaimersion/google-docs-utils/issues/10)).

Google App Script can interact with Google Docs programmatically. However, those extension I mentioned before seem that can work without it, just through local javaScript script. I'm not sure about 'LanguageTool', you can see it even can add a toolbar [item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2BmB.png).

Even with Google App Script, I only find an [API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html#createmenucaption) to add menu item. I really want to know how do they do it.